# How do I capitalize the first letter in an array of strings using method capitalize?

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods, capitalization

I created a simple program to ask a sports fan about some info. Here is the code I have so far:

```
puts "What's your favorite pro sport?"
favorite_sport = gets.chomp

puts "Who's your favorite team in the #{favorite_sport}?"
favorite_team = gets.chomp

puts "What city are they from?"
team_city = gets.chomp

puts "Who's your favorite player in the #{favorite_team} roster?"
favorite_player = gets.chomp

puts "What position does #{favorite_player} play?"
player_position = gets.chomp

puts "How many years has #{favorite_player} played in the #{favorite_sport}"
years_experience = gets.chomp

fan_info = [favorite_sport, favorite_team, team_city, favorite_player, player_position, years_experience]
puts fan_info
```

I want to have the program output the fan_info with the first letter of the string capitalized. How do I do this? I know I have to use the method `capitalize` but I am having trouble implementing this.

Here is an example of the input and output:

```
What's your favorite pro sport?
NFL
Who's your favorite team in the NFL?
Seahawks
What city are they from?
seattle
Who's your favorite player in the Seahawks roster?
wilson
What position does wilson play?
qb
How many years has wilson played in the NFL
1
NFL
Seahawks
seattle
wilson
qb
1
```

Comment: For the user input `"NFL"`, do you want the output to be `"Nfl"` or `"NFL"`?

Comment: Good catch! Yes , I did want to leave it to NFL. Even if it is not entered all capitalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to capitalize the first letter keeping the other letters intact (i.e., `"NFL"` stays to be `"NFL"`, and does not become `"Nfl"`), then do:

```
favorite_sport = gets.chomp.sub(/./, &:upcase)
...
```

Comment: Would this be on every gets.chomp?

Comment: Yes. Or, you can do that all at once for the strings in the array using `map`. In that case, it does not make sense to keep `chomp` separate. It should be put inside the `map` block as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
puts fan_info.map(&:capitalize)
```

This calls `#capitalize` on every string, builds a new array of all the results, and prints that out instead.

It's equivalent to something like this:

```
fan_info_capitalized = []
fan_info.each do |inf|
  fan_info_capitalized << inf.capitalize
end
puts fan_info_capitalized
```

Only much more compact.

Comment: The problem with using it this way is, `capitalize` will turn all characters in the string into lower-case, then upper-case the first character, destroying the case of proper names and abbreviations. `'foo BAR'.capitalize
# => "Foo bar"`

Comment: Indeed, the poster should see and remedy such things.